# Convert decimal currency to comma separated value

Tags: c#, .net

I get from a webservice the following strings:

`12.95`

or

`1,200.99`

Is there an option to convert these values to the following values without manipulating the string?

`12,95`

or

`1200,99`

I tried it with some Culture options but didn't get it right...

### EDIT

I tried this:

```
    //return string.Format( "{0:f2}", Convert.ToDecimal( price ) );
    //return string.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-de"), "{0:0}", price);

                

    NumberFormatInfo format = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();

    format.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
    format.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
    format.CurrencyGroupSeparator = "";

    return decimal.Parse(price).ToString(format);
```

Comment: Im pretty sure its based on the culture settings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265773/how-can-i-globally-set-the-culture-in-a-wpf-application

Comment: Also you should post what you have already attempted

Comment: Do you know the culture of the input (the web service)?

Comment: Culture seems to be en-US, out should be de-DE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var input = "1,200.99";

//Convert to decimal using US culture (or other culture using . as decimal separator)
decimal value = decimal.Parse(input, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));

//Convert to string using DE culture (or other culture using , as decimal separator)
string output = value.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("de-DE"));

Console.WriteLine(output); //1200,99
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks to you and all others! missing clue was adding the culture to the input string.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
    double number;
    double.TryParse("1,200.99", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"), out number);
    var formattedNumber = number.ToString(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
```

Then return or write out formattedNumber (whatever you need to do).

Comment: input: 4.95, number is then 495.0 and formattedNumber 495 ... my brain hurts ;)

Comment: The above code example assumes your machine has the same culture as the input, otherwise specify it in the TryParse method - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Given your problem with the input culture, I've updated the answer in case it helps others...

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.  First, what you have is a string, and so you cannot change the formatting of it as you're attempting to.  However, to achieve what you would like, you can parse the string into a decimal value and then use the formatting options for decimals to display it in any reasonable way.

Answer (score 0):

You may try for something like this:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###0}", 0);
```

or may be like this:

```
string str = yourNumber.Remove(",").Replace(".",",");
```

Answer (score 0):

Close enough tronc,

Try this snippet:

```
String curStr = "12.95";
Decimal decVal;
var valid = Decimal.TryParse(curStr, out decVal);
if (!valid) throw new Exception("Invalid format.");
String newFormat = decVal.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE"));
```

Within the **toString(...)** call, you can append a number after 'C' to specify how many decimal places should follow. E.g "C3".