# Decimal separated by comma for thousand value

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting, decimalformat

First of all excuse me for this stupid question. This is something with that I am stuck and didn't get anything around.

I am in need of decimal format where if value is something like-

```
15000.45 should go to => 15,000
150000.44 should go to => 150,000
```

**Note-**  I want to eliminate points value after period (.)

I've gone through input mask-

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ but couldn't find any helper mask.

Another resource I tried-

[Convert decimal currency to comma separated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955736/convert-decimal-currency-to-comma-separated-value)

But they are replacing point value replaced by comma, i.e. if value is something `15000.34` then it converts it to `15000,34`

I also tried it giving custom format as-  `value.ToString("0,00")` but doesn't help.

Please assist!

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN docs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx.    value.ToString("C") will give you what you want

Comment: You want to do two things: omit decimals and add a thousand separator. What do you want to happen with the decimals? What should happen with `1000.99`? Do you want to round, and if so, which rounding do you want to apply, or do you want to truncate? After deciding that, displaying with thousand separator is trivial. Anyway, see [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105770/net-string-format-to-add-commas-in-thousands-place-for-a-number): `{0:n0}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decimal d = 15000.45m;

d.ToString("#,#"); //15,000
// or clearer arguably:
d.ToString("N0"); //15,000
```

And it will work for millions:

```
1234567.45m -> 1,234,567;
```