# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture pool limitations with multiple silverlight apps in 1 site

Tags: asp.net, localization, silverlight-5.0

My dillema is this: I'm maintaining 3 silverlight apps that are hosted in 1 asp.net website. Each silverlight app is assumed as one entirely different application only accessed differently by its own aspx page. However old, this 3yr project hasn't seen the light of day yet.

Each silverlight app can be configured its own localization culture using the Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture. This means that one app can have fr-Fr and the other en-US.

My concern is that, from my understanding, that setting one culture by another user can affect other users as well with simultaneous multiple users logging in at the same time.

Are my fears logical? Or am I not understanding the concept behind this?

Comment: What do you mean by "other user"? A user on a different machine? Clearly the different apps will have distinctly configurable ui cultures as they run in different app domains (in fact different sandboxes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

After further research, there's no absolute way to configure localization on all threads in the pool. So the approach is safe.

I read the answer from this older stackoverflow answer:

[How can i globally set the Culture in a WPF Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265773/how-can-i-globally-set-the-culture-in-a-wpf-application)