# DateTimePicker + WPF + binding + accept dd/MM/yyyy via userinput

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datetimepicker

**Simplified Question:**

I have a datepicker in WPF. I enter a value 30/10/1983 in the textbox of the datepicker. I need the value to be posted back to my viewmodel, where in I have bound it to a DateTime? property.

Is there any way I can achieve this. mm/dd/yyyy format triggers a postback but not dd/mm/yyyy.

The DatePicker code is as below.

```
<DatePicker Grid.Row="2" Name="inputDate"
                Text="{Binding BirthDate,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                >

</DatePicker>
```

The view model property is as below.

```
private DateTime? birthDate;

    public DateTime? BirthDate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.birthDate;
        }
        set
        {
            this.birthDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("BirthDate");
        }
    }
```

I enter a value 10/10 into the datepicker textbox, the setter gets called with a value, but the moment I enter an entire date 30/10/1983, I still have the view model property which is equal to NULL.

I have changed the Format to English-UnitedKingdom, in the calendar settings, and my CurrentCulture reflects en-GB appropriately.

**Original Question:**

I have a datetimepicker control in WPF, which I have bound the text property to a Nullable DateTime in the view model.

The problem I am facing is when I enter a value in the format MM/dd/yyyy, I do get a value postback in the view model, indicating the new value.

But when I enter the value in dd/MM/yyyy format, I do not get a notification in the view model and the value is lost. The bound propertyin the view model is null.

The short date format is the one which I have specified in the calendar settings & dateFormat,  within which for a short date format I provide the entry as "dd/MM/yyyy".

Could someone please help me with this scenario where in I accept date in dd/MM/yyyy format, and I do not want to hardcode, I wish to pick up the short date format from the calendar settings and also, I wish to recieve the updated value in the view model too.

Comment: post your code or an example

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen I have posted a simplified question over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843658/datepicker-wpf-accepting-dd-mm-yyyy-format

Comment: @Sandepku, you should still show your relevant code, regardless of how simple your question now is.

Comment: Isn't your formatting problem just a `Culture` issue? For example, the default date format that is used in the UK is dd/mm/yyyy, whereas in some places in Europe, it is mm/dd/yyyy. Check the answer to the [How can i globally set the Culture in a WPF Application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265773/how-can-i-globally-set-the-culture-in-a-wpf-application) question to find out how to change the current `Culture`.

Comment: @Sheridan sorry about that

Comment: @Sheridan I have updated the question with sample code and what I ve tried to do, thank you

Comment: Can you bind the UI Element to a String Property on the view model, and with your code manipulate it to retrieve the correct date and perform validation on the UI?

Comment: What you are experiencing is the type safe nature of WPF data binding. Your `BirthDate` property will not be updated with an invalid value... if you typed 'hello' into the `DatePicker` control, this would also be prevented from reaching the property. The real question is *why* does WPF think that a valid date is an invalid date on your computer... that's why I thought about the `Culture` on your computer. I cannot reproduce your problem on my computer, as `30/10/1983` is a valid date here. What geographical location is your computer based in?

Comment: @Sheridan you mean to say you type 30/10, the view model gets updated with a value of 30/10/2014, without even losing focus?

Comment: @Sheridan my time zone is UTC+530, Chennai,Kolkota,NewDelhi, I am using English(United Kingdom) format.

Comment: @StefanoBafaro trying that approach, :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related that a not valid date will not set with a correct value your ViewModel DateTime property. So, you can intercept it and convert correctly with a CONVERTER.

An example:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string strValue = System.Convert.ToString(value);
        DateTime resultDateTime;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(strValue, out resultDateTime))
        {
            return resultDateTime;
        }
        return value;    
    }
```

And your XAML code will be like:

```
 <DatePicker 
     Text="{Binding BirthDate,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
     SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Text,
     Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}"
  />
```

Comment: DatePicker doesn't have a Text parameter.

Comment: @Teysz try look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.aspx

Comment: So I checked and I appareantly use "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePicker" and not "System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker". And the one that I use doesn't have the Text parameter.

Comment: Perfect, change the Binding to the DATE property instead the TEXT property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.date.aspx

Comment: I've done what you wrote, yet I do still get the American style date of MM/dd/yyyy. I can't seem to change it to format I want, dd/MM/yyyy. I even changed my windows locale setting from en-US to nl-NL. Still no luck :/

Comment: You can customize the date format! Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.dayformat

Comment: That only formats the day, month and year, I want to format the actual order of them to day month year instead of month day year

Comment: Maybe you can solve your issue setting the Culture in your View Constructor like this:
 CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

Comment: using  SelectedDate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=Text)  will cause a "System.StackOverflowException" Exception because it create a circular reference. :( Took me 2 hours to find out what was going on !

Comment: did you find the solution? I've the same issue