# DatePicker WPF + accepting dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datepicker

I have asked the question in the [below link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800006/datetimepicker-wpf-binding-accept-dd-mm-yyyy-via-userinput)

Since I got no answers, trying to simplify my question.

I have a datepicker in WPF. I enter a value 30/10/1983 in the textbox of the datepicker. I need the value to be posted back to my viewmodel, where in I have bound it to a DateTime? property.

Is there any way I can achieve this. mm/dd/yyyy format triggers a postback but not dd/mm/yyyy.

Thanks

Comment: Please do not knowingly add duplicate questions on Stack Overflow, as that is very frowned upon. Please read the [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) page of the Stack Overflow Help Center to find out why. Instead of duplicating your question, you can simply edit it and that will cause it to move to the top of the new questions collection.

Comment: @Sheridan thanks you did not downvote! and will take care henceforth