# ListView to display number as a currency

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an issue with my ListView. I want to display value as a currency, i.e

```
£150.02
```

Instead I get

```
£$150.02
```

Here is my code:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding value, StringFormat=£{0:C}}" />
```

Comment: `C` - output locale specific currency (which seems `$` in your case), and pound symbol is output as it is. Two options: change locale ([globally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1265773/1997232)?) or output manually (e.g. output currency value as `decimal` with prefix you want).

Comment: is it an option in VS2015? My other projects written in VS2013 display data as they should

Comment: @ati This has no changed since .NET 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `C` then it should works:

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding value, StringFormat=£{0}}"
```

Comment: it shows no data (empty field)

Comment: @arti ... Don't remove `0` just remove `C`. It should works!

Comment: This is not a solution, it is a work around. Correct solution would be to make currency symbol automatically fetch it according to current culture

Comment: it is solution, especially my app will be used in Czech Republic and they have to see it as a £ not their currency. All depends what do you want to achieve

Comment: @arti: you can set the culture as en-Gb explicitly as clemens suggested. That would be a proper method to achive it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change  the Language of the control

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

You are having an Extra £ remove it,

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding value, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" />
```

Comment: now it displays ££150.02, when i set it to StringFormat={0:C} it shows no data
isn't there an option in VS2015 to edit global value?

Comment: Use `StringFormat={0:C}` in xaml (without pound symbol).

Comment: VS2015 is not allowing me. got 7 errors

Comment: The XAML parser won't recognize the leading curly brace as the begin of a format string. Write `StringFormat={}{0:C}` to get around that.

Comment: thanks clemens :) after long time :)

Comment: It shows $ not £. Is it an option within VS2015? As i said, my other projects in VS2013 work perfectly fine. My whole system is set to UK. And i don't want to put extra code on each of my UserControls to achieve it

Comment: @arti: First of all it has nothing to do with VS2015.

Comment: `XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name)` uses the current culture. If your system is in the US, it shows you a `$`, in UK it will show a pound symbol. Mine is german, and shows me a `€` symbol. And it's not only the symbol, but also the correct format, like `100,00 €` as opposed to `$100.00`. More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: so how can you explain fact, my system is set to UK and displays $ ?

Comment: No idea. You can make it explicit by `Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("en-GB");`

Comment: @arti: did you check Region and Language > Additional Settings > Currency > Currency Symbol ?